# RuleBasedCollator getInstance Locale.US getRules returns empty string in Droid

Tags: java, android, locale

Using Eclipse in Windows.

This code works in JRE 1.8 (Comp level 1.7) desktop, (string is not empty).

But it's not working in Droid (Comp level 1.7 - 4.4W.2 API-20) (string is empty):

Code:

```
    RuleBasedCollator collTemp = (RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
    String usRules = collTemp.getRules(); //==String is Empty - why?
    usRules = usRules.replace(",'-'", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Documentation has this to say for the getRules() method

> The returned string will be empty unless you constructed the instance
>   yourself. The string forms of the collation rules are omitted to save
>   space on the device.

You can use the collator but it won't return the string representation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html#getRules()